# Calculate character capacity of a textbox with known Width and Height and Font in wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, .net-core

I am trying to calculate how many characters or Text can fit in a TextBox with Wrap.
And I want to remove the over flow text.
I am passing the string to a TextBox at runtime and I want to truncate the extra part of the string and display only the Substring which can easily fit into TextBox of dynamic width and Height and font.
User can specify any width and Height and any font.
Is there any way to calculate number of characters which can fit in the text box of given Height and Width in WPF?

I have Tried to achieve this like:

`

```
if (fontSize <=minimumFontSize && 
  formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace > textBoxWidth) 
 { 
  do { 
       //reduce length; 
       length -= 1; 
       truncationText = formattedText.Text.Truncate(length); 
       formattedText= GetFormattedText(myTextBox, truncationText); 
     }
   while (fontSize <=minimumFontSize && formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace > textBoxWidth)
```

`

Comment: You can try to calculate the size of each character with TextRenderer.MeasureText.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MiguelCarreira i will try and let you know thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have tried 
`if (fontSize <=minimumFontSize && formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace > textBoxWidth)
            {
                do
                {
                    //reduce length;
                    length -= 1;
                    truncationText = formattedText.Text.Truncate(length);
                    formattedText= GetFormattedText(myTextBox, truncationText);
                } while (fontSize <=minimumFontSize && formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace > textBoxWidth)`